# How to send file via HTTP from .NET app to PHP web page?

Tags: php, .net, http, webclient

What is the best way for a desktop `.NET` app to send a file over `HTTP` to a `PHP` web page?

The `.NET` app could use this code to upload the file:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    client.UploadFile(address, filePath);
}
```

Will having simply this in the `PHP` page allow the file to be uploaded?

```
file_put_contents(filename, file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `PHP` code that worked for me, instead of what is in the question:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```